# java Unsafe, how to interpret memory as an other type of object?

Tags: java, memory, unsafe

So I've read a few articles around but essentially since I want a fast I/O, I want to write a double array to a file. To do that I need to convert it to a byte array. Unfortunately this makes copying of data.

So I was wondering suing java Unsafe is it possible to make a byte[] variable which points to the address of the double[] array and just interpret the data as bytes rather than doubles?
I did not manage to find anywhere so far such example, only again how to use copying memory in order to do this. Any advices are appreciated!

Comment: You can use [ByteBuffer#asDoubleBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asDoubleBuffer()). This lets you work with the DoubleBuffer that actually changes the underlying ByteBuffer.

Comment: This article looks like it's doing what you want. http://java-performance.info/object-assignments-type-conversions-on-the-low-level-in-java/

Comment: If you want portability (32/64 bits) then I would go with Java NIO. Use a FileChannel, ByteBuffer (could be a direct byte buffer) and the DoubleBuffer.

Comment: Just wondering is there a way to do the opposite conversion from DoubleBuffer to ByteBuffer, since I do not want to change the underlying implementation which uses doubles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with a ByteBuffer you can hold it's reference and use them interchangably.

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(8 * n_doubles);
DoubleBuffer db = bb.asDoubleBuffer();
```

You can not read/write to either and view it as `byte`s or `double`s as the same memory is used.

If you want to avoid additional copies to a file, you can use a memory mapped region.

BTW: ByteBuffer uses Unsafe, but in a way which protects you.

Comment: Only problem, that this could encounter is if you are not responsible for the code producing the double[] array, for instance when you use other library code... Than you can't change that. 
In my case it is a solution, probably better. But I still like that @resueman pointed to, which shows the powers of Unsafe. Happy :)

Comment: @Belov You can access the double[] as if it was a byte[] but it won't actually be a byte[] or be in a ByteBuffer. You can do a raw memory copy, to reduce the work, but it would still be a copy.

Comment: well in my case I can't, since I will use later again the double[] as a double array, but if you only need to store it, without accessing the array again, than if you look in the article posted in the comments of my question by resueman, you can convert the double[] array to byte[] only by changing the headers for type and length in the saved offset in raw memory. Was an interesting exercise at least for me :).